# Dapp code in development with ganache will it also work in production

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, ganache

I have client code that works fine with *Ganache* local server, but will it work when I push it to production I mean will *Web3.js* connect lets say to a **BSC** rpcUrl network and function like on *localhost*. Here is sample code am talking about. Am confused cause I see people using
*Infura* and similar providers to connect with the blockchain even *Web3.js* has Html provider to connect with the chain...why whats the pros, con and limitation is my way ok

```
 let rpcUrl = 'https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org';
 this.web3 = new Web3(rpcUrl);
 this.contract = new this.web3.eth.Contract(this.ABI, this.contractAddress);
 return this.contract.methods.helloWorld().call().then(result => result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, every dApp should provide its own node provider for users. You can piggyback the connection from the MetaMask,  but in this case it just likely connects to the same `https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org` URL. Thus, your approach is correct assuming Binance keeps providing RPC URL for free for foreseeable future.

For more options of available Ethereum nodes, please see this website:

https://ethereumnodes.com/

Comment: Thanks for clarifying things for me, but that's the thing "node provider" why do I need it don't blockchains have public free RPC-URL endpoints like BSC to connect with web3.js and metamask. I build a contract add on a blockchain create a website to interact with it using web3..why do I need to pay for private providers to access my dapp like alchemy or infura  then why do they have gas fee for? you say every dApp should provide its own node provider what do you mean and what the hell Binance could close access to their blockchain for fee...this is what I cant understand

Comment: The blockchains do not have free public endpoints and they can be blocked in countries like China. In this case, Binance is subventing the cost of their chain from the fees from the users collected from their exchange.

Comment: For more interesting concept of transactionally paid RPC access, see https://www.pokt.network/